Value of $g$ in frictionless surface
According to first law of Newton, object remains in state of rest unless a net external force is applied. When a ball is dropped, considering there is air resistance, some force is required to balance the drag and keep its state of uniform velocity. That is done by gravity. So if there wasn't drag then the force that was wasted to balance drag can be used for acceleration, right? Will the value of $g$ change?

"...object remains in state of rest unless a net external force is applied." No. Not "at rest." An object upon which no net external force acts will move with constant velocity. It could be the case, that in some frame of reference, the constant value is zero. But any other constant velocity also is allowed by the law.

The title doesn't match your question.  Falling objects are not on a surface.  Please clarify.

You basic fault is this $a \neq g$, where $a = g - a_{drag}$ is a net acceleration for a falling object, where as $g$ is acceleration solely due to gravity of Earth and $a_{drag}$ is acceleration solely due to drag force. So to say each force adds own independent accelerations for the body. Btw keep in mind that drag depends on object velocity, so at some point net acceleration becomes zero as object reaches terminal velocity.

The value of $g$ does not change in the absence of air resistance. What changes is how much of the gravitational force results in acceleration. With air resistance, some of the gravitational force is used to balance the drag, reducing the net acceleration. But without air resistance, all of the gravitational force contributes to the acceleration of the object, leading to constant acceleration at $g$. So, while the ball would accelerate more without air resistance, the value of $g$ itself actually remains unchanged.
The value of $g$ is actually just derived from a close to earth surface approximation of Newton's law of universal gravitation:
$$ F = \frac{G\cdot M\cdot m}{r^2} $$
$$ ma = \frac{G\cdot M\cdot m}{r^2} $$
and since our acceleration is due to gravity we can set it to $g$:
$$ mg = \frac{G\cdot M\cdot m}{r^2} $$
Divide by $m$:
$$ g = \frac{G\cdot M}{r^2} $$
Substitute in the mass of the Earth for $M$, the radius of the earth for $r$, and $G$ is the universal gravitational constant ($G=6.674×10^{-11}\text{ N}.\text{m}^2/\text{kg}^2$).

To clarify: $g$ (standard gravity) is a constant, and it only varies if you’re doing something really cool.

@Incognito: Just to put this answer in slightly different words: don't think of $g$ as an acceleration. Think of it as a parameter that tells you how strong the gravitational force is near the surface of the Earth. If the only force acting on an object is the gravitational force exerted by the Earth, then the acceleration of the object just so happens (because $ma = F_g = mg$) to have the value $g$, but this is the only case in which $g$ is an acceleration. At all other times, it's just a parameter telling you how strong gravity is.
